# How to download a file using office.js excel add-in?

Tags: office-js, office-js-helpers

Is there any way to download a file using office.js excel add-in? 
Simple href is now downloading the file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample add-in that does this by using `XMLHttpRequest.open()`, and a library called FileSaver, at [Office Add-in JavaScript FileDownload](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-JavaScript-FileDownload).