# How to open a downloaded base64 file in desktop from outlook web add-in

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Is there a way to open up a downloaded base64 file in desktop from outlook web add-in ??
I have a requirement where i am downloading the file from my web add-in. Now i want to open the downloaded pdf file in desktop in native application (Acrobat Desktop).
I know that it's a security issue and web add-in works like any other web application running in sandboxed environment. But is there any way to achieve this ??

Answer (score 1):

Like any other web applications (web sites) Office web add-ins are run in a restricted environment (sandboxed) and can't operate with local files for security reasons. The best what you could do is to let users download the file or just display it on the task pane in your add-in.

For example, you may find the sample code in the [Trying to save a blob file in Outlook for macOS using javascript](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/503) post. Also see [How to download a file using office.js excel add-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52511238/how-to-download-a-file-using-office-js-excel-add-in) for more samples.